# What is the thread priority of UI thread?

Tags: android

What is the thread priority of UI thread? Is it 5, Thread.NORM_PRIORITY? I want to run a high priority thread, but don't want its priority higher than UI thread.

Comment: What prevents you from calling `Thread.getPriority` on the UI thread?

Comment: I can call Thread.getPriority, but I wonder whether there is a constant priority value associated to UI thread and whether UI thread priority changes across os versions or phones.

Answer (score 0):

I put this line:

```
 Log.d(TAG, "The priority of the main thread is ${android.os.Process.getThreadPriority(0)}")
```

inside onResume and got this in the logcat:

```
 The priority of the main thread is -10
```

Answer (score -1):

A normal AsyncTask or a different background service usually is enough.